# Div not being positioned right in FireFox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, html

I am having an issue positioning a `div`. Here is the `div`:

```
<div class="facebookHoverDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 15000; display: none">
<div class="calendar-hover-top"></div>
<div class="calendar-hover-middle">
    <div class="post-image"></div>
    <div class="facebook-icon">Facebook</div>
    <div class="post-content"><span id="facebook-text">content</span>
        <div class="post-date">This will be the date.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-hover-bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="twitterHoverDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 15000; display: none">
<div class="calendar-hover-top"></div>
<div class="calendar-hover-middle">
    <div class="twitter-icon">Twitter</div>
    <div class="post-content"><span id="twitter-text">content</span>
        <div class="post-date">This will be the date.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-hover-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I am using the following jQuery function to display a tooltip:

```
    function ShowToolTip(event, postType, postMessage, scheduleDate, customPostId, postId) {
        if (postType == 'Twitter') {
            $('.twitterHoverDiv .post-content #twitter-text').text(postMessage);
            $('.twitterHoverDiv .post-content .post-date').text(scheduleDate);
            $('.twitterHoverDiv').css("left", event.x - 65);
            $('.twitterHoverDiv').css("top", event.y - $('.twitterHoverDiv').height());


            $('.facebookHoverDiv').hide();
            $('.twitterHoverDiv').show();
        } else {
            $('.facebookHoverDiv .post-content #facebook-text').text(postMessage);
            var url = "http://host.mmm.dev.webedge.mcmurry.com/Media/Image.ashx?articleid=" + postId + "&custompostid=" + customPostId;
            //url = url.replace("undefined", "0");
            $('.facebookHoverDiv .post-image').css("background-image", "url('" + url + "')");
            $('.facebookHoverDiv .post-image').css("background-size", "100%");
            $('.facebookHoverDiv .post-content .post-date').text(scheduleDate);
            $('.facebookHoverDiv').css("left", event.x - 65);
            $('.facebookHoverDiv').css("top", event.y - $('.facebookHoverDiv').height());


            $('.twitterHoverDiv').hide();
            $('.facebookHoverDiv').show();
        }
    }
```

If I run this in Google Chrome, it works perfectly. However, if I run it in FireFox, the tooltip shows up in the upper left hand corner of the screen. The issue seems to be in the `$('.facebookHoverDiv').css("left", event.x - 65);` and the `$('.facebookHoverDiv').css("top", event.y - $('.facebookHoverDiv').height());` calls.

Do I need to so something specific for FireFox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just in case anyone else runs into this problem. The issue was caused by using the `event.x` and `event.y` properties. These properties exist in Chrome, but in other browsers they are called `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`. Changing the properties to this fixed my issue.

Comment: In the spec, they're called `clientX` and `clientY`.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent

Answer (score 0):

Set a unit

```
.css("left", (event.x - 65) + "px");
```

Do the same thing with top

Comment: Good suggestion, however, same issue as before.